# PHP array to XML function

Tags: php, xml, json, recursion

I'm receiving a JSON string in a PHP page :

```
$JSON = $_POST['submit'];

$Array = json_decode($JSON);

$xml = arrayToXML($Array,"","root");

echo $xml;
```

where [arrayToXML](http://codepad.org/MwVcDYVg) is a function I made for the puropose.

The function works fine, but there are a couple problems I'd like to fix:

**1.Duplicate Tags:**

Let's say we have a JSON string such as

```
{element:[{sub1:xxxx,sub2:xxx},{sub1:xxxx,sub2:xxx},{sub1:xxxx,sub2:xxx}]}
```

the corresponding XML would be like

```
<element>

    <sub1>xxxx</sub1>
    <sub2>xxx</sub2>

</element>

<element>

    <sub1>xxxx</sub1>
    <sub2>xxx</sub2>

</element>

<element>

    <sub1>xxxx</sub1>
    <sub2>xxx</sub2>

</element>
```

But the recursion of my function duplicates the first  tag and the last  one. I can see why it does so, but I can't figure out a way to fix it. So I solved this by preg_replacing duplicate tags. Is there a better way to fix this? It's really been couple days I've been thinking on this.

**2. Indentation:**

I wanted the function to generate the xml in a fancy human readable way, so I put newlines between adjacent tags, but how can I define correct nested indentation?

I tryied this:

```
$xml = preg_replace("/(\t*)(<\/?.+>)(<\/?.+>)/","$2\n$1\t$3",$xml);
```

but turns out to be compleately wrog. What would be a correct one?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can convert json to XML with [PEAR::XML_Serializer](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer). Firstly, convert json to an object then convert the object to XML

Comment: the function should be correctly linked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions are poor for parsing and working with `xml` in general.  PHP has very nice built-in parsers with `DOMDocument` (wrapper for the awesome libxml2) and `SimpleXML`.

Comment: SimpleXML is definitely the way to go if you've never used either of these before.

Answer (score 1):

refering to the first doubt "duplicate tag", I think that the best that you can do is to change the JSON string to the right structure you need, if you need more than one phone number element change the JSON string to have more than a phone number element, perhaps you can do something like preg_replace or identify the struture of the array to change it, but that would be a kind of workaround.
but generally, I'm agree with Explosion Pills, you have tools that you can use to parse that array.